# EE3 Template Partials

Tags: template-partials

I upgraded a dev site to EE3 and my snippets are now placed into two folders, _global_partials and _partials. I can't seem to find the difference on what these folders are. At first I thought it may have something to do with template variables but adding a new template variable just puts it in a folder called _variables. EE3 docs don't seem to have what the difference between the two folders are. Has anyone figured out the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard from anyone in a while but I think I figured out the answer. I believe the _global_partials folder is used when you have multiple sites, while the _partials folder is on a per site basis. Ellislabs still doesn't have any documentation so I can't provide a true answer.